# Basic question about Merging faces

Tags: modeling

I'm a beginner with blender so this is probably a very basic question.

I have this basic model below. I've ended up with a lot of unwanted geometry that I want to simplify.
I wanted to start by merging the two selected faces below but no matter what I try to delete or merge it just destroys the geometry.

How can I achieve what I want to do (which is combining all of the unwanted geometry, either starting with this merge or some other way?)

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select the faces you want to merge, press <kbd>Del</kbd> or <kbd>X</kbd> and click *limited dissolve*.

[image]

Comment: This is what I tried originally, but nothing happens when I do it at all.
 it does work when I try it on a simple cube, so I'm assuming something is different here?

Comment: Could you post your .blend file?

Comment: I don't know what had gone wrong but I started again and it worked exactly as you described so thank you.